# Multiply lists of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, products

Hello I would like to multiply a list of matrices by another list of matrices and return all elements. I.e.

```
K={A,B,C}
L={X,Y}
```

And the result should be

```
K.L={A.X,B.X,C.X,A.Y,B.Y,C.Y}
```

I tried

```
Outer[Dot,A,B]
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Does `Dot @@@ Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {x, y}}]` give what you need?

Comment: .. or `Join @@ Transpose@Outer[Dot, {a, b, c}, {x, y}]`?

Comment: It does! The order is slightly different - it is  `{a.x, a.y,....}` but it doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: @kglr, make an answer dude and we will upvote it!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dot @@@ Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {x, y}}]
(* or *) Join @@ Transpose@Outer[Dot, {a, b, c}, {x, y}]
(* or *) Distribute[{{a, b, c}, {x, y}}, List, List, List, Dot]
```

> {a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y, c.x, c.y}

If the order matters use `SortBy`:

```
Dot @@@ Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {x, y}}] // SortBy[#, Last]&
```

> {a.x, b.x, c.x, a.y, b.y, c.y}

Or, if you have version 10 or 11, just `SortBy[Last]` instead of `SortBy[#, Last]&`.